# How to do load data if textbox sets User Input without submit button?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to load data when someone puts 6 numbers in my textbox. How can i achieve that?
I know how to load data but I dont know how to trigger for example the method that loads the data when someone types in 6 numbers in my textbox.

// Edit for more Information

I use the MVVM pattern. I check if there are only numbers with an PreviewTextInput like this:

```
        private void PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex("[^0-9]+");
            e.Handled = regex.IsMatch(e.Text);

        }
```

The textbox is bound to an ID (just an int) property

```
        private int _id;
        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { OnPropertyChanged(ref _id, value); }
        }
```

What is the best or clearest way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you use the TextChanged event, and then check the the .Text.Length == 6? (and validate the input is all numbers)

Comment: Clarify if you are using MVVM and bindings or are you doing everything in the Code Behind Window?
Also wondering how do you implement "numbers only"?
Highly recommended if you also supplement your question with a part of your code.

Comment: Is this a good way for mvvm pattern? I edited my Question with more information

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the TextChanged event on the textBox, and then check if the TextBox1.Text.Length == 6

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using MVVM, then, in general, you need to implement the bound property check in its setter.
When it exceeds 100K, call the required method.

```
private int _id;
public int ID 
{
   get => _id;
   set
   {
      OnPropertyChanged(ref _id, value);
      if (value >= 100_000)
         Method(value);
  }
}
```

This code is demo and implementation may differ depending on the BaseViewModel used.
But I think you understand the meaning of the proposed option.

There are also nuances if it is necessary to provide the possibility of entering leading zeros.
Then a different implementation is required with binding to the string property.
But the meaning will be the same.

Comment: Is it allowed to invoke a method in the model? becauuse my setters and getters are in the model.

Comment: Depends on the specific implementation.
Try it.
If it doesn't work, give a little more code so that you can understand what the problem is.

Comment: It does not work. The method that i want to invoke is in my ViewModel but I dont know how to do it.

Comment: I do not understand what prevents you from calling this method as shown in my example.
Can you show what this method is? His signature?

Comment: Because I dont want to call it from my Model. In the Model are only properties with setters and getters. I dont have the method right now. But the method will just get data from an sql database.